# Package convention when working with java, unit testing and cucumber bdd

Tags: spring, unit-testing, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I want to modify my actual project so I can put the integration test on the same repo.
Right now i have something like

*src

**main

***java

****com.example

** test

***groovy

****com.example

I have all the unit test on src/test/groovy/com/example and the code on src/main/java/com/example now I want to add the specs related to cucumber somewhere on the project 
I can not find if there is any convention to this so I'm asking here to see if i can find some answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up doing 
`src/test` 
`src/main` 
`src/e2e`

- Was easier to getting more control on what I want to execute when doing `./gradlew test`.
- Also I found on gradle page a lot of tutorials on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Convention is to use the same: `src/main/` and `src/test/`
You might create a separate package inside `src/test/` for your Cucumber test code (to separate from unit / integration tests).
And put your feature files somewhere in `src/test/resources`.

For an example, see the [10-minute tutorial](http://docs.cucumber.io/guides/10-minute-tutorial/) or [my blog](https://medium.com/@mlvandijk/getting-started-with-cucumber-in-java-a-10-minute-tutorial-586652d2c82) on getting started with Cucumber in Java.

**Sidenote** (Not sure on which language you plan to use for your Cucumber tests): You should be aware that [cucumber-jvm-groovy](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm-groovy) is looking for a new maintainer; unless you're up for that, you might prefer to use [cucumber-jvm](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm) with either Java or Kotlin for your Cucumber tests.